# Elliptic PDEs in Finance

Tags: pr.probability, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, stochastic-differential-equations, mathematical-finance

In mathematical finance, one often encounters *parabolic PDEs* typically through the Feynman-Kac representation theorem/formula.  However, I'm curious are there interesting examples of Elliptic *boundary value problems* in mathematical finance?

I came across this Q&A: "[Hyperbolic and Elliptic PDEs in Quant Finance](https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/60818/70758)" on the [Quantitative Finance StackExchange](https://quant.stackexchange.com), but I cannot find a clear mathematical formulation of a "perpetual exchange option" (whatever that is)...

Comment: Long shot, but they may be relevant in ergodic control problems, where the long term behaviour of SDE and stationary measures is what matters.

Comment: @NateRiver That sounds like a nice example, do you know of a reference?

Comment: I do not, unfortunately.

Comment: A perpetual exchange option would be an option to trade one asset for another that never expires.  For example, you could have the option to trade 1 share of Apple for 1 share of Microsoft at the time of your choosing, until the end of time.

Comment: Ya that's cool.  I think I may go for a nice control problem given by some reasonable BSDE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For elliptic PDE applications to options these would need be independent of time, they need to be perpetual (i.e. never expire), which is not a typical scenario. If your definition of "mathematical finance" includes insurance mathematics, there is one application.

[A deep neural network algorithm for semilinear elliptic PDEs with applications in insurance mathematics](https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.15757) (2010)

> In insurance mathematics, optimal control problems over an infinite
> time horizon arise when computing risk measures. An example of such a
> risk measure is the expected discounted future dividend payments. The
> solutions to such control problems correspond to solutions of
> deterministic semilinear (degenerate) elliptic partial differential
> equations.