# Elliptic PDEs in BSDEs and in optimal control

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, stochastic-processes, oc.optimization-and-control, elliptic-pde, stochastic-calculus

This *soft/reference* question is related to [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/462400/elliptic-pdes-in-finance) of a similar nature.

What are some examples of elliptic PDEs appearing in control and BSDEs?